# Apache Solr date field conversion error in java

Tags: java, solr, type-conversion, date-conversion

I have a problem with a solr Date format. In a jar file the following row generates a conversion error:

```
**cannot cast 'java.util.ArrayList' to 'java.util.Date'**
Date date = (Date) list.get(0).getFieldValue(fieldName);
```

The line that generates the error is from mycore-oai-2019.11.jar and MCROAISolrSearcher.java class and as you know I cant change it.

The date column in solr is saved in the following format:

```
 "modified":["2018-08-17T06:10:55Z"]
```

Debbuging the code in that row I see the following Date format :

[image]

I cant understand the error! I am trying for hours to figure it out but nothing. Is the Timezone the problem? Is the mapping of the field a problem? Please any advice/help would safe me!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The field in Solr is a multivalued field - the code expects it to be single valued. A multi valued field returns a list (that's the arraylist you're seeing), while a single valued field returns the field directly (which would be the Date field). Fix your schema and re-index.

Comment: Thank you that was the case. Changed the field in cdate and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The field in Solr is a multivalued field - the code expects it to be single valued. A multi valued field returns a list (that's the arraylist you're seeing), while a single valued field returns the field directly (which would be the Date field).

Change your schema (remove `multiValued="true"` or explicitly set `multiValued="false"`) for the field) and re-index.

By default, in schemaless mode, all fields are multivalued, so that's usually why this appears - you haven't explicitly configured your schema (which you should do in production use).